# Getting the sum of the first and last value in a vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, sum

I would like to get the the sum of the first last element in a vector

Here is what I tried,for some reason I keep getting the value is zero. what should I change.

```
int sum_first_last(vector <int> &v) {
for (int k = 0; k < v.size(); ++k) {
        if (k == 0) {
            int first_element;
            first_element = v[k];

            if (k == v.size()) {
                int last_element;
                last_element = v[k];
                return first_element + last_element;
            }
 }

int main() {

    vector<int> v1;
    int n;
    int k = 0;
    cout << "please enter number of elements you wish to add" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "enter the value" << endl;
        cin >> k;
        v1.push_back(k);
    }

    sum_first_last(v1);
    cout << "the value is " << sum_first_last(v1) << endl;

    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: `if (k == v.size()) {` note that `v[v.size()]` is out of bounds. Although why are you looping at all?

Comment: sum = vec[0] + vec[vec.size()-1];

Comment: @seccpur After checking that the size isn't zero of course.

Comment: "for some reason I keep getting the value is zero" please note that strictly speaking you should include the input, output and expected output in the question. Getting a zero as result can be fine, unless thats not the correct result, but we dont know what you use as input

Comment: you have a `}` missing and actually I dont know how this method can return anything, as inside the loop `k` cannot be `0` and `size()` (should be `size()-1`) at the same time (unless there is only one element)

Comment: You get 0 because of Undefined Behavior (because you did not return a value from a non void function) and the code never enters the `if (k == v.size()) {` although if it would that would be UB also because of my first comment. The value returned could be anything because of the UB in the code. And the code is missing several `}` like @user463035818 mentioned above.

Comment: Please do read about [mcve]

Answer (score 8):

You can compute the desired value by

```
const int sum = vec.front() + vec.back();
```

You don't want to invoke this on an empty vector, though, so make sure `vec.empty()` returns false beforehand.

```
const int sum = vec.empty() ? 0 : vec.front() + vec.back();
```

For a vector with one element, this will be identical to `const int sum = 2*vec.front()`.

Comment: thanks,works. Could you explain why used const? and not just int?

Comment: There is no need to assign another value to the object `sum` after it's created. Then it's good practice to explicitly qualify the object `const`. If you need to re-assign something else to it, don't use `const`.

Comment: If the vector has only 1 element, I think summing that single element should be the element value by itself, not 2x the value. `const int sum = vec.empty() ? 0 : (vec.size() == 1) ? vec.front() : (vec.front() + vec.back());`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, that's a tweak that makes sense. I couldn't figure out how the OP wanted this case to be handled, so I shipped around the chained ternary operator...